# EF migrations Code First. Add column to database if column doesn't exist

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I need to add a column to a table if that column doesn't exist. Reason: in some database we have such column and in some - not. I've added field to my model and create migration:

```
public override void Up()
{           
    AddColumn("dbo.NavFilters", "Promo", c => c.String(maxLength: 100, nullable:true));
}

public override void Down()
{
    DropColumn("dbo.NavFilters", "Promo");
}
```

How can I check is the column exists?

Comment: You should write SQL manually and put it inside Sql("") method. Also this is very bad if your application is connected to different databases, which have different schema. What's the reason behind this?

Comment: This solution I've used, but wonder, how can I do it using C#

Comment: There is no other way. The only way is not to have different schema databases beyond one DbContext.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No way to do it using standard DbMigration methods.
The best way is to include a "select fieldToCheck from myTable where 1=2" into a try catch then add the field if required (in catch).

The other way is to write a custom migration generator that extends the Migration generator (i.e. adding an AddColumnIfNotExists method). You can have a look here to see how to do it:
http://romiller.com/2013/02/27/ef6-writing-your-own-code-first-migration-operations/

Answer (score 21):

I have worked on creating a custom migration method, AddColumnIfNotExists

You need a custom MigrationOperation class:

```
public class AddColumnIfNotExistsOperation : MigrationOperation
{
    public readonly string Table;
    public readonly string Name;
    public readonly ColumnModel ColumnModel;

    public AddColumnIfNotExistsOperation(string table, string name, Func<ColumnBuilder, ColumnModel> columnAction, object anonymousArguments) : base(anonymousArguments)
    {
        ArgumentValidator.CheckForEmptyArgument(table, nameof(table));
        ArgumentValidator.CheckForEmptyArgument(name, nameof(name));
        ArgumentValidator.CheckForNullArgument(columnAction, nameof(columnAction));

        Table = table;
        Name = name;

        ColumnModel = columnAction(new ColumnBuilder());
        ColumnModel.Name = name;

    }

    public override bool IsDestructiveChange => false;

    public override MigrationOperation Inverse => new DropColumnOperation(Table, Name, removedAnnotations: ColumnModel.Annotations.ToDictionary(s => s.Key,s => (object)s.Value) , anonymousArguments: null);
}
```

You also need a custom SqlGenerator class:

```
public class AddColumnIfNotExistsSqlGenerator : SqlServerMigrationSqlGenerator
{
    protected override void Generate(MigrationOperation migrationOperation)
    {
        var operation = migrationOperation as AddColumnIfNotExistsOperation;
        if (operation == null) return;

        using (var writer = Writer())
        {
            writer.WriteLine("IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM sys.columns");
            writer.WriteLine($"WHERE Name = N'{operation.Name}' AND Object_ID = Object_ID(N'{Name(operation.Table)}'))");
            writer.WriteLine("BEGIN");
            writer.WriteLine("ALTER TABLE ");
            writer.WriteLine(Name(operation.Table));
            writer.Write(" ADD ");

            var column = operation.ColumnModel;
            Generate(column, writer);

            if (column.IsNullable != null
                && !column.IsNullable.Value
                && (column.DefaultValue == null)
                && (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(column.DefaultValueSql))
                && !column.IsIdentity
                && !column.IsTimestamp
                && !column.StoreType.EqualsIgnoreCase("rowversion")
                && !column.StoreType.EqualsIgnoreCase("timestamp"))
            {
                writer.Write(" DEFAULT ");

                if (column.Type == PrimitiveTypeKind.DateTime)
                {
                    writer.Write(Generate(DateTime.Parse("1900-01-01 00:00:00", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)));
                }
                else
                {
                    writer.Write(Generate((dynamic)column.ClrDefaultValue));
                }
            }

            writer.WriteLine("END");



            Statement(writer);
        }
    }
}
```

And an Extension Method to give you your "AddColumnIfNotExists" function:

```
public static class MigrationExtensions
{
    public static void AddColumnIfNotExists(this DbMigration migration, string table, string name, Func<ColumnBuilder, ColumnModel> columnAction, object anonymousArguments = null)
    {
        ((IDbMigration)migration)
          .AddOperation(new AddColumnIfNotExistsOperation(table, name, columnAction, anonymousArguments));
    }
}
```

In your EF Migrations Configuration file, you need to register the custom SQL generator:

```
[ExcludeFromCodeCoverage]
internal sealed class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<YourDbContext>
{
    public Configuration()
    {
        AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = false;

        // Register our custom generator
        SetSqlGenerator("System.Data.SqlClient", new AddColumnIfNotExistsSqlGenerator());
    }
}
```

And then you should be able to use it in place of AddColum like this (notice the **this** keyword):

```
[ExcludeFromCodeCoverage]
public partial class AddVersionAndChangeActivity : DbMigration
{
    public override void Up()
    {
        this.AddColumnIfNotExists("dbo.Action", "VersionId", c => c.Guid(nullable: false));
        AlterColumn("dbo.Action", "Activity", c => c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 8000, unicode: false));
    }

    public override void Down()
    {
        AlterColumn("dbo.Action", "Activity", c => c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 50));
        DropColumn("dbo.Action", "VersionId");
    }
}
```

And of course you want some tests for the operation:

```
[TestClass]
public class AddColumnIfNotExistsOperationTests
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void Can_get_and_set_table_and_column_info()
    {
        Func<ColumnBuilder, ColumnModel> action = c => c.Decimal(name: "T");

        var addColumnOperation = new AddColumnIfNotExistsOperation("T", "C", action, null);

        Assert.AreEqual("T", addColumnOperation.Table);
        Assert.AreEqual("C", addColumnOperation.Name);
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void Inverse_should_produce_drop_column_operation()
    {
        Func<ColumnBuilder, ColumnModel> action = c => c.Decimal(name: "C", annotations: new Dictionary<string, AnnotationValues> { { "A1", new AnnotationValues(null, "V1") } });

        var addColumnOperation = new AddColumnIfNotExistsOperation("T", "C", action, null);

        var dropColumnOperation = (DropColumnOperation)addColumnOperation.Inverse;

        Assert.AreEqual("C", dropColumnOperation.Name);
        Assert.AreEqual("T", dropColumnOperation.Table);
        Assert.AreEqual("V1", ((AnnotationValues)dropColumnOperation.RemovedAnnotations["A1"]).NewValue);
        Assert.IsNull(((AnnotationValues)dropColumnOperation.RemovedAnnotations["A1"]).OldValue);
    }

    [TestMethod]
    [ExpectedException(typeof(ArgumentNullException))]
    public void Ctor_should_validate_preconditions_tableName()
    {
        Func<ColumnBuilder, ColumnModel> action = c => c.Decimal(name: "T");
        // ReSharper disable once ObjectCreationAsStatement
        new AddColumnIfNotExistsOperation(null, "T", action, null);
    }

    [TestMethod]
    [ExpectedException(typeof(ArgumentNullException))]
    public void Ctor_should_validate_preconditions_columnName()
    {
        Func<ColumnBuilder, ColumnModel> action = c => c.Decimal();
        // ReSharper disable once ObjectCreationAsStatement
        new AddColumnIfNotExistsOperation("T", null, action, null);
    }

    [TestMethod]
    [ExpectedException(typeof(ArgumentNullException))]
    public void Ctor_should_validate_preconditions_columnAction()
    {
        // ReSharper disable once ObjectCreationAsStatement
        new AddColumnIfNotExistsOperation("T", "C", null, null);
    }
}
```

And tests for the SQL Generator:

```
[TestClass]
public class AddColumnIfNotExistsSqlGeneratorTests
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void AddColumnIfNotExistsSqlGenerator_Generate_can_output_add_column_statement_for_GUID_and_uses_newid()
    {
        var migrationSqlGenerator = new AddColumnIfNotExistsSqlGenerator();


        Func<ColumnBuilder, ColumnModel> action = c => c.Guid(nullable: false, identity: true, name: "Bar");


        var addColumnOperation = new AddColumnIfNotExistsOperation("Foo", "bar", action, null);

        var sql = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, migrationSqlGenerator.Generate(new[] {addColumnOperation}, "2005")
            .Select(s => s.Sql));


        Assert.IsTrue(sql.Contains("IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM sys.columns"));
        Assert.IsTrue(sql.Contains("WHERE Name = N\'bar\' AND Object_ID = Object_ID(N\'[Foo]\'))"));
        Assert.IsTrue(sql.Contains("BEGIN"));
        Assert.IsTrue(sql.Contains("ALTER TABLE"));
        Assert.IsTrue(sql.Contains("[Foo]"));
        Assert.IsTrue(sql.Contains("ADD [bar] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL DEFAULT newsequentialid()END"));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Basic example with sql:

```
// add colun if not exists
migrationBuilder.Sql(
@"IF COL_LENGTH('schemaName.TableName', 'ColumnName') IS NULL
     ALTER TABLE[TableName] ADD[ColumnName] int NULL
     GO
");
```

Comment: Whilst this doesn't look at formal as the popular answer, it's instantly understandable and adaptable. And it works.

Answer (score 0):

I created the following extension method with the code from dgzornoza's answer:

```
    public static OperationBuilder<SqlOperation> AddColumnIfNotExists(
        this MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder,
        string table,
        string name,
        string type,
        bool nullable = false)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(table))
            {
                throw new ArgumentException($"'{nameof(table)}' cannot be null or empty.", nameof(table));
            }

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(name))
            {
                throw new ArgumentException($"'{nameof(name)}' cannot be null or empty.", nameof(name));
            }

            return migrationBuilder.Sql(@$"IF COL_LENGTH('[dbo].[{table}]', '{name}') IS NULL
     ALTER TABLE[{table}] ADD[{name}] {type} {(nullable ? "NULL" : "")}
     GO
");
        }
```